# Execute function across multiple columns based on condition in another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with multiple columns for words and one column for the size of the sentence to which they belong:

```
set.seed(1)
 df <- data.frame(
  w1 = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 10, replace = T),
  w2 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace = T),
  w3 = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10, replace = T),
  w4 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T),
  w5 = sample(LETTERS[1:6], 10, replace = T),
  size = sample(1:3, 10, replace = T)
)
df
   w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 size
1   A  A  D  C  E    2
2   A  A  A  C  D    3
3   B  C  C  C  E    2
4   B  B  A  A  D    1
5   A  C  B  E  D    1
6   B  B  B  D  E    1
7   B  C  A  D  A    1
8   B  C  B  A  C    2
9   B  B  D  D  E    2
10  A  C  B  C  E    2
```

What I need to do is get the total number of unique words in the columns. That's easily done for the dataframe as a whole:

```
apply(df[,1:5], 2, function(x) length(unique(x)))
w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 
 2  3  4  4  4
```

But what I really want is the total of unique words per column and *per sentence size*. So I tried `tapply`:

```
tapply(df[,1:5], df$size, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

To no avail--there's this error:

```
Error in tapply(df[, 1:5], df$size, function(x) length(unique(x))) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

What's wrong with this code? How can it be improved?

Comment: You need `aggregate`, `aggregate(.~size, df, function(x) length(unique(x)))`

Comment: That looks good--thanks!